# Is ajax functionality affected when a page and its master page are not located in the same directoty?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The applications have several projects, such as Timesheet, payroll, and tax, all depending on the same Master page. The **MasterPage** is located in completely different directory. The problem is that **Ajax** has never worked. Now I start if that's the reason Ajax is not working.

There is a ScriptManager control on the master page. When we try updatepanel in pages, nothing happens.

I've created a small aplication and placed **ScriptManager** in the Master page. It worked.

Is ajax functionality affected when a page and its master page are not located in the same directoty? Just to rule out some causes so that I can concentrate somewhere else.

## EDIT

Project path can be something like:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My_Application\My_Project
```

While the Master page could be in the following directory

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\controls\My_MasterPage.Master
```

Thansk for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Pages and Master page can be in different directories. Ajax won't be affected because of they being in different directories.

Comment: By different directories, I gave the the path in the EDIT.